# How do i precicely add all the packages that are required for the deployment of my py file on Streamlit

Tags: python, deployment, streamlit

I my code is running locally and i need to deploy it on streamlit as a part of my university project. However, how do i know what are the exact dependencies needed to deploy the app? I used PyCharm for the development. I pushed the project on Git but i still need a requirements.txt .
What are the steps to generate that?

I tried redeploying it with every "Not found" Error. But it seems to be not working and I need a more efficient way to do so. Is there some way i can generate it?

Comment: What third party libraries did you install?

Comment: Did you try this? [requirements.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73799646/19290081)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pip freeze > requirements.txt`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_freeze/) for this